# What does 'supra-textual' mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, word-meaning

Are there any synonyms of that word? Or a definition?

> The ‘Snapewives’ or ‘Snapists’ are women who channel Snape, are
>   engaged in romantic relationships with him, and see him as a vital
>   guide for their daily lives. In this context, Snape is viewed as more
>   than a mere fictional creation. He is seen as a being that extends
>   beyond the Harry Potter texts with Rowling perceived as a flawed
>   interpreter of his **supra-textual essence**.'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

His essence "above", that is, outside of or beyond the text, transcending the text.

The passage itself glosses **supra-textual essence**: "a being that extends beyond the ... texts".